# Term for number of edges in a graph

Tags: graphs

Is there a single-word term for "the number of edges in a graph"?  Something along the lines of "arity" for function parameters.

Comment: Anything against $|E|$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably call this the "Edge-cardinality" of the graph, and it's denoted $|E|$, where your graph $G = (V,E)$. Similarly, the "vertex-cardinality" is the number of vertices, denoted $|V|$, though $|G|$ is sometimes also used to denote $|V|$.

The edge count isn't always considered that important, because you (almost) always have at least $|V|$ edges, and you can't have more than $|V|(|V|-1)$ edges in a digraph. So for issues of complexity, the node count tends to matter more.

Comment: It's funny, I would provide the exact same reasoning as you, but draw the opposite conclusion. You seem to think of sparse graphs as the exception, whereas I think of them as the norm -- I'm hard pressed to think of any real-world graphs that are not sparse. The only difference between a tree and a graph of the same vertex cardinality is the edge cardinality, and algorithms that work beautifully on the former can completely choke on the latter. So it seems to me that edge cardinality is what usually matters, not node cardinality. You usually can't avoid visiting edges any more than nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a single word term for this. *Edge count* seems to be the closest thing to what you are after. Mathematically it can be expressed as **E(g)**.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeCount.html